# Tableau Server Won't Load

Tags: tableau-api

I wanted to enabled custom scheduling for our Tableau Server. I followed the instruction on https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/schedule_enable_custom.htm but the server won't start again. It says Error state. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you did:

```
tsm configuration set –k features.SelfServiceSchedules -v true
```

then run:

```
tsm configuration set –k features.SelfServiceSchedules -v false
tsm pending-changes apply
```

and try to restart.

Comment: Are you able to run a `tsm status -v` to see if you have any services running?

Comment: Yes, I ran tsm status -v. A few services are running but most are in error state.